# How to enable spring transaction logger

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging

I'm trying to enable a transaction logger for spring 3.1.3, but I don't see any message about transaction in my console.

My spring spring-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd" default-autowire="byName">


     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClass}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.connectionURL}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" 
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
        p:persistenceUnitName="myUnit"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
                <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

My log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.com.myCompany=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p (%13F:%L) - %m%n


log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate your methods with @Transactional to make them participate in a transaction?

Comment: Yes I annotated a few services, but I'm not able to see a log messages with the configuration above

Comment: When jetty try to deploy the application i get this message:  No Transaction manager found if your webapp requires one, please configure one